# Can I configure liquibase to use an ssh tunnel?

Tags: liquibase, ssh-tunnel

I use an ssh tunnel to connect to various databases. Can I somehow tell liquibase to use this as well (through liquibase.properties or by other means)?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in with Liquibase to tunnel over SSH. There are ways to address this outside of Liquibase; for example, you could setup port forwarding so that Liquibase calls are properly sent over the network to the remote database(s).